# Message encryption in kafka streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, apache-kafka-streams

I am recently trying to play with kafka streaming for some sensitive data processing. The goal I wish to achieve is that while the sensitive data is encrypted, the power of microservice architecture is not jeopardised, i.e., losely coupled services and stream data processing.

My question is, in kafka streaming, is it possible that I decrypt an incoming message using one key and encrypt it again with another key? I kind of got a plan, but as I am not familiar with kafka streaming, I can not prove that kafka streaming is capable of handling this function, using Streams DSL. Can anyone help me with this question, and preferably, tell me which function in Streams DSL can handle that?

Update: Basically, what I am asking is: I am trying to use public key encryption twice for a single message in the streaming pipeline. Once on the inbound topic and once on the outbound topic. Just not sure if DSL is able to decrypt and encrypt, and where the keys should be stored.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're simply wanting to prevent others from inspecting your data, Kafka provides SSL connection for encryption between clients and brokers, although the at-rest data will still be unencrypted. You can add SASL to additional add authorization to limit who can access the cluster. Limiting SSH access to get to the broker files would also help

What you are asking for requires [a custom Serializer and Deserializer combination](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/datatypes#implementing-custom-serdes), which is used by all Kafka APIs.

When using the Kafka Streams API, you would wrap these in a Serde class and provide that to your streams properties before you start it, or between two DSL methods by `Produced.with` or `Consumed.with`

Comment: I am afraid that is not what I am asking. I am asking, is it possible to decrypt and encrypt a message within the Kafka streaming pipeline, during the data processing stage where DSL is playing.

Comment: encryption is simply a wrapper around the serialization

Comment: Unless you mean adding SSL to the entire Kafka installation... which is outside the scope of your single application

Comment: NONO, I am trying to use public key encryption twice for a single message in the streaming pipeline. Once on the inbound topic and once on the outbound topic. Just not sure if DSL is able to decrypt and encrypt, and where the keys should be stored.

Comment: Kafka has no form of message encryption outside of SSL. In order to encrypt anything, you need to muck with the bytes of the message.. That's *exactly what the serializer interface is for*. Therefore, if you plan to do this in Streams DSL or Processor API, you would have to do it via a Serde. You could even just use the `BytesSerde`, then `map()` and encrypt the data on your own... You can configure the serializers with any properties you want via their `configure` methods, which can then load a file/cert from your filesystem

Comment: Thanks for your answer cricket_007! My another question is, is it possible that I automatically update the keys in the Serde while the pipeline is already running?

Comment: The serde is only available to change at compile time, not runtime